# How to send and receive data via bluetooth BLE?

Tags: c#, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have just started working with arduino/bluetooth and i am now looking to work with it and send and recieve commands via an app.

I am currently working with a bluetooth BLE device that I want to connect to both iOS and android but I am scratching my head a bit on how to correctly send and recieve data (byte[]) to the device via bluetooth BLE.

In order to send and recieve info between the app and the bluetooth/arduino i work with `ICharacteristic` (that i think is the correct interface in order to send data via BLE) but I am unsure on how I should connect that to the device that I find.

I will show my code so you can see my clearly what I mean.

```
public class bluetoothConnection
{
    public IAdapter thisAdapter { get; set; }
    public ICharacteristic thisCharacteristic {get; set;} 
}
```

my connect-function where I connect to the exact device by its name and UUID. If i find something then my button where I try to send data will be enabled and useable.

```
public async void connect()
{
    await myConnection.thisAdapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();

    myConnection.thisAdapter.DeviceDiscovered += async (sender, e) =>
    {
            if (e.Device.Id.ToString().Equals ("00001101 - 0000 - 1000 - 8000 - 00805f9b34fb" && e.Device.Name == "HC-05"))
            {
                await myConnection.thisAdapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(e.Device);
                sendCommandButton.IsEnabled = true; //so my button is enabled and that function is below
            }
    };
}
```

So this button below is enabled if i find my bluetooth device from my arduino and now I try to send info to my arduino but how do I connect `thisCharacteristic`to the device that I just found above?

```
byte[] byteText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("send this textline");

void sendCommandToArduino(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    myConnection.thisCharacteristic.WriteAsync(byteText);
}
```

This is how I read to see if the arduino sent anything to the app:

```
var info = myConnection.thisCharacteristic.ReadAsync();
var result = info.Result;
string textresult = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
```

I would of course put this in a while loop to constantly look for data.

So my question is: In order to send data via bluetooth (app and BLE device) do I use `ICharacteristic`(with my current nuget that i use) and if so, how do I connect `ICharacteristic`to the device that I found in order to send and recieve data via bluetooth BLE?

Comment: have you tried the `StartUpdatesAsync()` method on the characteristic? that should connect you to the characteristic for Reading and Writing

Comment: @skar ah ok, but do i not need to connect my ICharacteristics with my device somehow? How do the `ICharacteristics` know to what device it will send it's data? Or does it automaticlly recognize that when you are connected to a bluetooth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't already done so, check your Arduino device documentation to see which characteristic you need to be writing to/reading from. A characteristic will be a "child" of a specific service. Both services and characteristics have UUIDs that you can use to reference them.

On your mobile app, you should initiate a service discovery phase when your BLE device is connected. When you have obtained the service, you can search and get a reference to your characteristic. Something along the lines of:

```
var service = await connectedDevice.GetServiceAsync(Guid.Parse("<service-uuid-here>"));
var characteristic = await service.GetCharacteristicAsync(Guid.Parse("<characteristic-uuid-here>"));

// ...

characteristic.WriteAsync(message);
```

Comment: Alright! Thanks a lot for the answer. Cleared a lot of questions that i had. I am using  this module: http://www.ebay.com/itm/HM-10-BLE-Bluetooth-4-0-CC2540-CC2541-Serial-Wireless-Module-Arduino-Android-IOS-/141783453254?hash=item2102f3ce46:g:QSAAAOSwKIpWA624 I will have to read about what to send to this particular device! But I would guess it is a characteristic.